# MySQL: Update multiple rows with random values

Tags: python, mysql, random, sql-update, date-arithmetic

I have a table called `rainfall`. It has 2 columns (**sensorID**, **area**,  **time**, **rainfall**, **redalert**)

[image]

I want to fill the **time** column with random times in intervals of 5 minutes (e.g 12:55, 04:30, 07:45) . I managed to get the random times by using this Python code:

```
import mysql.connector
import random
import datetime
import time


MINTIME = datetime.datetime(2020,4,1,0,0,0)
MAXTIME = datetime.datetime(2020,7,1,0,0,0)

mintime_str = int(time.mktime(MINTIME.timetuple())) #convert date to INT
maxtime_str = int(time.mktime(MAXTIME.timetuple())) #convert date to INT

no_steps = (maxtime_str - mintime_str)//(5*6) #state the number of minutes interval to 5 minutes

sql = "UPDATE rainfall SET date = %s"
rand = ''

for RECORD in range(108):
    random_slot = random.randint(0, no_steps)
    random_ts = mintime_str + 5*60 * random_slot
    RANDOMTIME = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(random_ts)
    rand = datetime.datetime.strftime(RANDOMTIME, '%H:%M')


val = (rand,)


mycursor.execute(sql, val)

raindb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "record(s) affected")
```

The problem is that this code fill all rows in **time** with 1 value only:

[image]

I need different values in each row. It fine if some rows have duplicate time values.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with SQL only:

```
update rainfall  
set time = concat(
  lpad(floor(rand() * 24), 2, '0'),
  ':',
  lpad(floor(rand() * 12) * 5, 2, '0')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `rand()` as follows:

```
update rainfall 
set time = sec_to_time(floor(rand() * 60 * 60 * 24 / (5 * 60) * 5 * 60)
```

Expression `rand() * 60 * 60 * 24` gives you a random number of seconds that represents a time. You can then use `floor()` and multiplication to round it to the nearest 5 minutes. Finally, `time_to_sec()` turns it to a `time`.

Comment: That's much easier. But it round it to the nearest 5 seconds.

Comment: @AhmedA: my bad! Fixed.